# Authorizing with Spotify API

Tags: api, authentication, heroku, oauth, spotify

I've set up authorization through Spotify on my project, it works locally and on my Heroku staging environment but not my Heroku production environment. It either times out or remains on a blank page. Was able to get it to Spotify Login through Facebook once, but upon submission it times out. Have no idea what may be causing this, wondering if its because a custom domain was added to the app.

```js
   
   onSuccess = (response, mutation) => {
     this.setState({error: false, loading: true})
     mutation({
       variables: { accessToken: response.access_token}
     })
     .then((res) => {
       this.setState({loading: false})
       this.props.history.push(`/`)
       window.location.reload();
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       this.setState({loading: false})
       this.setState({error: true, errorMsg: "Something went wrong, please try again"})
     })
   }

  onFailure = (response) => {
    this.setState({click: false, error: true, errorMsg: "Something went wrong, please try again"})
  }
   
   
   
   <SpotifyLogin
      clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_ID}
      onClick={() => this.setState({click: true})}
      redirectUri={process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_URL || "http://localhost:3000/"}
      onSuccess={(data) => this.onSuccess(data, mutation)}
      onFailure={this.onFailure}
      scope="user-read-private user-top-read user-read-email user-read-playback-state"
      className="onboarding__spotify-cta"
    />
```

[image: blank page upon login]

Comment: Please, provide us some code if you want some help.

Comment: Just added! Wasn't sure it would help in this situation. @JonathanDelean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem are not in you dev environnement but on your prod, it's cause you have a probleme with your redirect uri, check your `process.env.REACT_APP_SPOTIFY_URL` if it's the good one

Comment: Thought I had that covered but I was missing a character, appreciate the help!